# Programmatically create packages.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package-restore

I am programmatically generating a Visual Studio project. The project in question requires some Nuget packages.

I create a file called packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The first time the project is run it will download the package.  The problem is that if a new version is released it will always download version 7.0.1.

Is there a way to tell it to get the newest version?  Is there a way to programmatically ask NuGet what the latest version is so that I can add it to my project when its generated?

I have tried removing Version and adding version="*" neither has worked.

**update**:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json"  targetFramework="net45" />
```

gives the following error

> NuGet Package restore failed for project SampleProject: Unable to
>   parse version value '' from 'packages.config'

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="*"  targetFramework="net45" />
```

> Error 2   NuGet Package restore failed for project SampleProject: Unable
>   to parse version value '*' from 'packages.config'

It would appear that version is required.   I am hoping that someone knows of some way of tricking it to find the current version.

Comment: It should work. What happens if you removed the `targetFramework` attribute? ;)

Comment: removing targetFramework doesn't appear to affect the errors I just posted.   Was a good thought though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell NuGet up to which version of a package it is allowed to upgrade using an additional attribute on the package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="SomePackage" version="2.1.0" allowedVersions="[2,3)" />
</packages>
```

But this will still not automatically upgrade to the latest version of the package, simply because there may be breaking changes. It will allow your users to upgrade with relative safety to a higher version, since you're explicitly telling them that you've tested these higher versions or trust the author not to make breaking changes. See also: https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning

Currently, locking a package to a specific version range requires hand-edited the packages.config file and can't be done through the UI.

The official way to do this is for you to package your project as a vsix, include the nuget package in the vsix and release a new version every time your dependencies change, after testing that the new version actually works.

There is no system in place in NuGet which automatically updates all your packages. Though nothing is stopping you from calling `Update-Package 'YourPackageName'` from your own extension or project/item creation wizard using the [IWizard interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) to trigger your code when your project or project item is added to the project and [using the NuGet objects to invoke the upgrade task](https://docs.nuget.org/create/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.   I have stopped generating the packages.config file and am just going to instruct the users to add the NuGet package themselves.